# How is the battery life on the new iPod Touch G5s?

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

I had an iPod Touch G4 and the battery life was terrible.  Has there been any improvement in this area with the G5s?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the **Technical Specifications** ([5G](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP657), [4G](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP594?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)) no big change is apparent, as the only difference between them is the lasting time while playing videos, as it's up to **8 hours** (when fully charged) for the 5G while the 4G's is **7 hours**.

They both share the following battery specifications:

> Built-in rechargeable lithium-ion battery.
>
> Music playback time: Up to 40 hours when fully charged.
>
> Charging times: Fast charge in about 2 hours (80% capacity), full charge in about 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I've owned both, and the battery life in the 5th generation is much better. In [Ars Technica's review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/10/the-price-of-progress-2012-ipod-touch-reviewed/4/) they find that the iPod Touch will last about 7 and a half hours while being actively used (in their test they were browsing the web, streaming Spotify and Netflix, and playing some games).